# Function in controller isn't called using Laravel 8

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-routing

I'm trying to build a dynamic dropdown list for countries and cities so:

I have the following view:

```
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                           <label>Pays</label>
                           <select class="form-control select2-single" data-width="100%" 
                              name="pays" id="pays">
                             <option label="&nbsp;">&nbsp;</option>
                             @foreach($countries as $country)
                           <option  data-id="{{$country->id}}" value="{{$country->name}}"> 
                           {{$country->name}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                           </select>
                       </div>

                       <div class="col-sm-6">
                           <label>Ville</label>
                           <select class="form-control select2-single" data-width="100%" 
                              name="ville" id="ville">
                           </select>
                       </div>
                  </div>
```

And the following script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  
  $(document).ready(function(){
       
       $("#pays").change(function(){
          /* let country_id = this.value;*/
          let country_id = $(this).find("option:selected").data("id");
           $.get('/getState?country='+country_id,function(data){
              $("#ville").html(data);
           });
       });

/*  });*/

</script>
```

And my controller:

```
 public function getAllStates()
 
    {
        $country_id = request('country');

        $states = State::where('country_id',$country_id)->get();

       /* dd($states);*/
    
        $option = "<option value = ''> Select State</option>";


        foreach($states as $state){
            $option.= '<option value = "'.$state->name.'">'.$state->name.'</option>';
        }
        return $option;
    }
```

And the following route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','role:admin']], function() { 
  Route::get('/getState/{country}','App\Http\Controllers\CastingController@getAllStates');
});
```

The problem is the function `getAllStates` isn't called, there is something wrong with my route?

Comment: Open your network tab -> XHR ..what you see there ?

Comment: I see nothing in XHR , the route is incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script calls the route with a query parameter whereas the route is defined with a route segment.

So you have to change your JavaScript:

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
       
       $("#pays").change(function(){
          /* let country_id = this.value;*/
          let country_id = $(this).find("option:selected").data("id");
           $.get('/getState/'+country_id,function(data){
              $("#ville").html(data);
           });
       });

/*  });*/
```

Comment: it still the same problem

Comment: If you open your DevTools, what do you see in the network tab? What does `$.get()` return (status code, error message, etc.)?

Comment: I see nothing ,

Comment: What does "nothing" mean? Do you get a 200 HTTP response code?